# Fire JS script more than once

Tags: javascript

I want to display a countdown on a page more than once but I can't get it to fire more than once. Is there a way this can be done I was thinking a for each might work for this?

https://jsfiddle.net/3a4m71vo/

```
    function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
      var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
      var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
      var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
      var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

      return {
        'total': t,
        'days': days,
        'hours': hours,
        'minutes': minutes,
      };
     }

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.querySelector(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var oneMinute = 60000;

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);

    if (t.total < oneMinute) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
      clock.style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = 'September 29 2019 13:18:00';



initializeClock('.js-countdown', deadline);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you were facing is that you weren't using IDs for your html/javascript. Instead you were passing the class of the html (div).

I've added two blocks of html and given them ids, `one` and `two`.

Thus:

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.querySelector(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var oneMinute = 60000;

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);

    if (t.total < oneMinute) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
      clock.style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}


initializeClock('#one', 'September 29 2019 13:18:00');

initializeClock('#two', 'September 28 2019 13:10:00');
```

```css
.countdown__counter {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}

.countdown__counter-item {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="one" class="countdown__counter js-countdown">
  <div class="countdown__counter-item">
    <span class="days bond-countdown__time"></span>
    <div class="bond-countdown__small-text">D</div>
  </div>

  <div class="countdown__counter-item">
    <span class="hours countdown__time"></span>
    <div class="bond-countdown__small-text">H</div>
  </div>

  <div class="countdown__counter-item">
    <span class="minutes countdown__time"></span>
    <div class="countdown__small-text">M</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="countdown__counter js-countdown">
  <div class="countdown__counter-item">
    <span class="days bond-countdown__time"></span>
    <div class="bond-countdown__small-text">D</div>
  </div>

  <div class="countdown__counter-item">
    <span class="hours countdown__time"></span>
    <div class="bond-countdown__small-text">H</div>
  </div>

  <div class="countdown__counter-item">
    <span class="minutes countdown__time"></span>
    <div class="countdown__small-text">M</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="two" class="countdown__counter js-countdown">
  <div class="countdown__counter-item">
    <span class="days bond-countdown__time"></span>
    <div class="bond-countdown__small-text">D</div>
  </div>

  <div class="countdown__counter-item">
    <span class="hours countdown__time"></span>
    <div class="bond-countdown__small-text">H</div>
  </div>

  <div class="countdown__counter-item">
    <span class="minutes countdown__time"></span>
    <div class="countdown__small-text">M</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="countdown__counter js-countdown">
  <div class="countdown__counter-item">
    <span class="days bond-countdown__time"></span>
    <div class="bond-countdown__small-text">D</div>
  </div>

  <div class="countdown__counter-item">
    <span class="hours countdown__time"></span>
    <div class="bond-countdown__small-text">H</div>
  </div>

  <div class="countdown__counter-item">
    <span class="minutes countdown__time"></span>
    <div class="countdown__small-text">M</div>
  </div>
</div>
```